# Посадить ребенка или сажать ребенка на колени?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов

В тесте предлагается выбрать верный вариант ответа:

> а) садить ребенка на колени;
>   б) сажать ребенка на колени;
>   в) оба варианта неверны;
>   г) оба варианта верны.

Садить - просторечное, хорошо. Но *сажать* ребенка на колени режет слух. Может, верным было бы *посадить* его на колени?

Comment: Пример: С какого месяца можно сажать ребенка себе на колени? Вроде бы слух не режет.

Comment: @Sharon, да, видимо, у меня что-то со слухом не то, все верно!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из толкового словаря.

САЖАТЬ 2. кого. Просить, заставлять или давать возможность сесть. С. гостя. С. кого-л. за один стол с кем-л. **С. ребёнка на колени.** С. с собой обедать.

Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.